# Hire my own surveyor or trust my neighbor's?

Tags: real-estate

A neighbor with whom I share a property line has informed me that the fence we thought was on that property line is incorrectly placed. Of course it's too far on his side. Should I hire my own surveyor to verify his claim? Or can I trust that the surveyor he hired is impartial and competent?

Comment: The big question I would be asking is "how much is the current fence line worth to you?" Based on that you can then decide how much money it is worth to investigate and/or fight his claims.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can the surveyor provide you a printed copy of the results? If so you can take those to another surveyor and just ask if he or she thinks it's worth revisiting.

Most surveyors don't want to waste their time.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. The other surveyor was willing to do it if I wanted, but he didn't seem to think it was very likely he would find any differences.